# Can you get the information which child called constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm trying to get information about which child called parents constructor. I'm not allowed to pass the argument onto the constructor. Is something like this possible?

```
class Parent {
 Parent() {
  Console.WriteLine("Child1 called me");
 }

}
class Child1: Parent {
 string name;
 Child1(string name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

}
class Child2: Parent {
 string surname;
 Child1(string surname) {
  this.surname = surname;
 }

}
```

Comment: eeehm, what? can you please provide some code and what you want to achieve?

Comment: *I'm not allowed to pass the argument*. It is because it is against the principle of inheritance. the parent shouldn't aware of the executer by design. it is probably an x.y problem. What you trying to achieve?

Comment: The usual approach is to invert the control: have the base constructor call a virtual method that derived classes override to customize behavior.

Comment: by parent / child here, are you talking about an object hierarchy? or different objects? if hierarchy: you still have `GetType()` (which is non-`virtual`, so you can't get into much trouble with it); if different objects... I'm confused how the child exists before the parent

Comment: So... `GetType()` ?

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do that. This would violate OOP principles. If you explain what you want to achieve, there are probably much more elegant ways of doing that

Comment: If you're from a C++ background, you may be thinking of C++ construction where objects change their types as constructors are invoked. This is not the same in C#, the object has it's final type immediately, even when parent constructors are being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetType()` will still work here, and is non-`virtual` (which limits how much trouble you can get into re uninitialized fields, which is a problem when calling `virtual` methods from a constructor); you can always explore the tree if multiple types are involved:

```cs
    public Parent()
    {
        var type = GetType();
        while (type != typeof(Parent) && type != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
```

If we have:

```cs
class Child3 : Child2
{
    public Child3(string surname) : base(surname) { }
}
// ...
new Child3("whatever");
```

Then this will output:

```
Child3
Child2
```

Comment: @ChrisBD there is no such restriction in .NET; what you *can't* do is inherit from multiple base classes at the same time (something you can do in C++) - you can inherit from at most one class, but implement any number of *interfaces*